# jQuery mobile style is lost when i change view with Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm using require.js, jquerymobile, backbone and handlebars.
I have a cordova multi-view app.
When I change view in my app, i fire the event with:

```
Backbone.history.navigate("page", {trigger: true});
```

In my router page, I have kinda:

```
routes: {
                "page": "page",
    },

initialize: function () {
            this.currentView = undefined;
            var page;
            page = new Login();
            this.changePage(page);
            },

page: function () {
        var myview = new View({});
        this.changePage(myview );
    },

changePage: function (page) {
        if(this.currentView) {
            this.currentView.remove();
            this.currentView.off();
            }
        this.currentView = page;
        page.render();
    }
```

When i change page, the template is loaded but it is like jquerymobile style is lost.
JQM is included the first time in my main.js file, after the require.config, where I launch the router.

Comment: Isn't there a "bind jQuery Mobile to this dynamic HTML" function you can call? You probably need to manually bind all the JQM stuff to your view's `el`.

Comment: I think not. I only use:

require(["router","jQueryMobile"], function(Router) {
new Router();
}

Comment: But how is JQM supposed to know about things that aren't present in the DOM when JQM is loaded? Check the *Related* list in the sidebar, this is almost certainly a duplicate.

Comment: can you include brief code for page.render and main.js, this may help